# Switching Between Branches On Drupal Website With git

Tags: git, drupal, version-control

So I'm working on a Drupal website and I want to start using git to play around with different ways of implementing functionality without destroying the old implementation (in case the new way turns out to be rubbish).

Say I pull the master from the repository on the server (the same server with the Drupal installation on it) and then make a new branch, feature1, and then decide to make another branch from that called feature1b which is implemented differently. To test my code I need it to be on the server with the Drupal installation, so I would have to commit my branch back to master on the server.

What is the best way to push both branches to the server, without them being merged to master *and* being able to switch between them to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what are you asking is:

> How to push changes to a new branch on remote server?

and the answer is:

```
git push <your remote name> feature1
```

this will create branch feature1 on your remote (Drupal) server, then you can check it out and see how it works